# @overrides for C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a way in C++ to ensure that a virtual method in a subclass is in fact overriding a super class virtual method? Sometimes when I refactor, I forget a method and then wonder why it is not being called but I forgot to change the method signature so it is no longer overriding anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible in C++11, with the `override` identifier:

```
struct Base {    
  virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "Base::foo!\n"; }
};

struct Derived : virtual public Base {
  virtual void foo() const override {std::cout << "Derived::foo!\n";}
};
```

This allows you to find out at compile time whether you are failing to override a method. Here, we neglect to make the method `const`:

```
struct BadDerived : virtual public Base {
  virtual void foo() override {std::cout << "BadDerived::foo!\n";} // FAIL! Compiler finds our mistake.

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [feature of C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final) using the `override` keyword.

If you use Visual C++ 2005 or newer, you can use the [explicit override feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8ew2153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as well without needing C++11 support.

As for implementation status across various compilers, refer to [Apache stdcxx's site](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport).

GCC 4.7.0 implements the feature, MSVC implements the standardized version as of Visual C++ 11.0 (will ship with Visual Studio 2012's release).

Comment: That "explicit override feature" is C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: Minor nitpick, override is not a keyword, but an identifier. I think it is not a keyword to avoid breaking C++03 code.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - I seem to remember there being an extension from Microsoft to implement the `override` feature in native C++, instead of just C++/CLI. I might be mistaken. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8ew2153(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @birryree You are correct. It is available for native c++ as well.